# Deprecation issue for InternetExplorerDriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, ie

I want to use PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY strategy while launching IE driver by using the following code but I'm facing a deprecation issue for InternetExplorerDriver. What's the reason for it?

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY, "none");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```

InternetExplorerDriver is crossed out as indicated in the screenshot.

[image: Deprecation]

Comment: Did you read the docs or source for that class? If it's marked as deprecated, there's usually an explanation or alternative: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriver.html#InternetExplorerDriver-org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities-

Comment: Yes, i did and it didnt work for me. how can i get rid of this deprecated issue ? how should i type the code to handle it

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? What did you change? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

The docs say you have to instantiate the driver with a different argument type: *InternetExplorerOptions*:

[image]

*InternetExplorerOptions* have [a method called *setPageLoadStrategy*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerOptions.html#setPageLoadStrategy-org.openqa.selenium.PageLoadStrategy-):

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions().setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
```

You can find all strategies [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/PageLoadStrategy.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.150.1\\IEDriverServer.exe");

InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions().setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);

options.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: Please also try to explain why your solution solves the problem.